# ggplot binwidth not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have just started to learn R and gglpot, so please bear with me.

I am trying to see price per carat in the `diamonds` dataset.

I first used

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price, y = carat)) + geom_histogram()
```

then I got an error `Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic.`

Next I learned the `stat = "identity"` and used

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price, y = carat)) + geom_histogram(stat="identity")
```

to get `Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad` and a graph with too many bins.

I tried to set the binwidth as

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price, y = carat)) + geom_histogram(stat="identity", binwidth = 1000)
```

but still the warning persists and I get too many bins.

What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From `?geom_histogram`: "Visualise the distribution of a *single* continuous variable..." A histogram is useful if you want to look at the distribution of diamonds in different carat ranges, OR the distribution of prices in different price ranges. Not both at the same time.

Comment: If you want the distribution of price per carat, you probably need to preprocess the dataset to calculate that. E.g.: `ggplot(diamonds %>% group_by(carat) %>% summarise(price = mean(price)) %>% mutate(mean.price = price/carat), aes(mean.price)) + geom_histogram()`

Comment: @Z.Lin, ok! I understand this to some extent (not quite confident with the complex thing you wrote though). Any other geometry to visualize this?

Comment: @Z.Lin, however I don't understand if `geom_histogram` is not meant for this, how is the plot happening? Only problem is it has `too many bins`.

Comment: By stating `stat = "identity"`, you overrode the default connection between `geom_histogram` & `stat_bin`. Hence it behaved similar to a `geom_bar`, with each price occupying 1 "bin" & bar height equal to the carat corresponding to that price. I suggest you google for examples of ggplot2 using different geoms to get a better understanding of how they work. Here's a guide that uses the diamond dataset for illustration: http://varianceexplained.org/RData/code/code_lesson2/

Comment: @Z.Lin, yes! Now I get it. Thanks for the help. :)